# Custom logo manage by customizer and theme options

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options, logo

I have created a custom theme options page and added some theme setting fields and I also added the custom-logo option in Customizer, all thing are working well, but I want the logo also to be managed by the theme options page. That means when I add a logo from theme options page it also updates on the customizer page and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [`set_theme_mod()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/get_theme_mod):

> Creates or updates a modification setting for the current theme

and [`get_theme_mod()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/get_theme_mod):

> Retrieves a modification setting for the current theme

With this you should be able to get the logo:

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$logo = wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full' );
```

This would set the attachment 12 as the logo

```
$attachment_id = 12;
set_theme_mod( 'custom_logo', $attachment_id );
```

Hope, this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much dear it works but I have one more issue when I add the logo from theme options page it also updates on Customizer page its awesome but when I change the logo from Customizer page and close the page it comes on theme options page and logo is not change. Please have a look of my 3kb size of theme here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByFyWkWITLC7RkZ4UTliS0U1X0E/view?usp=sharing) of my theme

All theme option code in functions.php file

Comment: I had a quick look. Why do you update each time with `set_theme_mod` the custom_logo with the image from `$options['logo_url']`? But I guess your problem is now not really related to your question above and you should probably open a new question.

Comment: Thank you for see my theme. I have no idea how to ask this type of problem. I would request you please If you have any solution for this issue so please let me know

Comment: Oh! I am fool, It was very easy

`// set image to the customizer
        if (  isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] )== true ){ 
        set_theme_mod( 'custom_logo', $image_id );`
 
        }